# how to prevent Chinese Simplified IME auto switch to english in textbox in windows 11

Tags: windows-11, ime

When i want to type in a textbox , the Chinese Simplified IME auto switch to English from Chinese.
Example: I was typing in a textbox, when i want to switch IME language, it instantly switch to english from chinese.

textbox : anywhere can typing such as textpad, google search etc

I tried this way:

- reinstall it
- change to Chinese Traditional IME.
  Unfortunately, it's not working.

How to fix it?

Comment: Type into where ?  Applications have to support this in some fashion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta type into textbox.Example: textpad, google search etc

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/input-method-editor-ime-is-disabled-in-windows-10) for some fixes. If one works, then post it as an answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta not work, its not IME disabled i think, i can change ime to chinese when not hover on the textbox.But when i type , the IME instantly change to english